# How to draw a line around a sphere

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Is there an addon or something to draw a line on a sphere or to be able to rotate the camera while drawing?
I tried with the anchored stroke and it only looks good in front but behind it has a part where the line is too wide, also I had to do it looking from below, so if I want to make a line above the one I did I can't because the camera angle doesn't reach that part.
Also searched on google about the curve stroke, but it also depends on the camera angle.
[image: Front]

[image: Back]

Comment: @Gorgious I'm already using an outliner, but I don't want to create extra topology for those lines, I just want to paint them around the hairballs.

Comment: Is it wider on the back because you're painting in a perspective view? What does (Numpad-5) switching to orthographic do for you?

Comment: @RobinBetts you're right, I didn't know that button was to switch the view until you switch it again (I thought it was like pressing 1 to switch to ortographic view, but once you move the camera, it goes back to perspective)

Comment: Hi, @Kai ! There's a setting for 'Auto Perspective'  in Edit > Preferences : https://imgur.com/a/i3RYBsH  If these comments add up to a fix, could you self-answer to resolve your question? This is not really my area, and I can't demo on your model.  If I draw a line-stroke with 'Occlusion' off, and 'Cull Backfaces'  off, I'm nearly there, but with frustrating gaps on the sides. You're clearly very good at this.. I love your model :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as a comment said, use the orthographic view instead the perspective, by looking from below in ortographic view you can have almost all the sphere in the perfect angle to paint the lines [image: painted with ortographic]

[image: Back]